# scalaz 7 equivalent of `<|*|>` from scalaz 6

Tags: scala, scalaz, scalaz7

In [Nick Partridge's presentation on deriving scalaz](https://vimeo.com/10482466), based on an older version of scalaz, he introduces validations using a function:

```
def even(x: Int): Validation[NonEmptyList[String], Int] =
  if (x % 2 == 0) x.success else { s"not even: $x".wrapNel.failure }
```

Then he combines this using

```
even(1) <|*|> even(2)
```

which applies the test and returns a validation with the failure message. Using scalaz 7 I get

```
scala> even(1) <|*|> even(2)
<console>:18: error: value <|*|> is not a member of scalaz.Validation[scalaz.NonEmptyList[String],Int]
       even(1) <|*|> even(2)
               ^
```

What is the scalaz 7 equivalent of this combinator?

Comment: Wouldn't you rather want to use `|@|` operator ? The video you posted does not mention it but you can find out more about it here:
http://eed3si9n.com/learning-scalaz/Validation.html

Comment: In particular you can then write `scala> (even(1) |@| even(2) |@| even(3)) { _ + _ + _}` `<console>Failure(NonEmptyList(not even: 1, not even: 3))` and
  `scala> (even(2) |@| even(4) |@| even(6)) { _ + _ + _})` `<console> Success(12)`

Comment: @mjaskowski `|@|` is very generic, and in cases where you just want to zip together two values in a tuple, `tuple` (previously known as `<|*|>`) is more appropriate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is now called `tuple`, so you can write for example:

```
import scalaz._, Scalaz._

def even(x: Int): Validation[NonEmptyList[String], Int] =
  if (x % 2 == 0) x.success else s"not even: $x".failureNel

val pair: ValidationNel[String, (Int, Int)] = even(1) tuple even(2)
```

Unfortunately I'm not sure there's a better way to find out this kind of thing than checking out the last 6.0 tag of the source, searching, and then comparing signatures.

Comment: There was a deprecation annotation pointing one to `tuple` in 7.0, but this is naturally gone in 7.1.

Comment: There is a typo. failNel should be failureNel

Comment: @Cloudtech `failNel` is still around in 7.1, but it's deprecated, so I've changed it.

Answer (score -1):

You want to use the `|@|` operator.

```
scala> (even(1) |@| even(2) |@| even(3)) { (_,_,_) }
<console> Failure(NonEmptyList(not even: 1, not even: 3))

scala> (even(2) |@| even(4) |@| even(6)) { (_,_,_) }
<console> Success((2,4,6))
```

compare that to `tuple` operator:

```
scala> even(1) tuple even(2) tuple even(3)
<console> Failure(NonEmptyList(not even: 1, not even: 3))

scala> even(2) tuple even(4) tuple even(6)
<console> Success(((2,4),6))
```

Comment: You definitely _can_ use `|@|` here, but I don't see any indication that that's what the OP _wants_. `|@|` existed in Scalaz 6 and did the same thing as it does in 7—`<|*|>` is something more specific that had its named changed.

Comment: What good is `tuple` over `|@|` in the scenario of Validation?

Comment: Why does the scenario matter? When you want a tuple, `tuple` is more precise, less powerful, more readable, and more clear about intent than `|@|`—these are all reasons to prefer it.

Comment: Well anyway, for someone learning about Validation, knowledge about `|@|` is at least as important as knowledge about `tuple`. And in the particular example in question both are fine.